# How would I write a redirect rule in my routes.rb for this structure of a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

So I have a URL that was generated from an old CMS that I am migrating away from. What I want to do, is rather than supporting the old URL structure, just do a permanent 301 redirect to the new one.

But the only way to know the new one is if the title is the same/similar.

So I have no idea if this is even possible, but here are some examples of what the URL differences:

====== OLD =======

http://www.example.com/rbt/26741-pnpyo-saddened-at-passing-of-roger-clarke.html

====== NEW =======

http://www.example.com/pnpyo-saddened-at-passing-of-roger-clarke

====== OLD =======

http://www.example.com/rbt/26766-algaj-pays-tribute-to-the-honourable-roger-clarke.html

====== NEW =======

http://www.example.com/algaj-pays-tribute-to-the-honourable-roger-clarke

====== OLD =======

http://www.example.com/rbt/26738-pnp-chairman-expresses-shock%2C-grief-at-clarke%E2%80%99s-passing.html

====== NEW =======

http://www.example.com/pnp-chairman-expresses-shock-grief-at-clarke-s-passing

So the key differences in the URL structure are the prefix `/rbt/12345` where `12345` is some ID, `/rbt/` is a static string/directory name, the way the URL was encoded (e.g. it handles apostrophes, etc. horribly) and an extension at the end.

Ideally, it would be nice if my `routes.rb` rule could look at each of the above old URL requests and do a permanent 301 redirect to the new and improved URL.

Is this even possible? If so, what might that look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to set up the redirect (301) in config/routes.rb

```
# old path
get '/rbt/:name', to: redirect {|path_params, _| "/#{path_params[:name].gsub(/^\d+\-/, '')}" } 
# new path
get ':name',      to: 'posts#show'
```

Then ensure that you have a controller (in this case blog), to catch the new redirect.

You can read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

Comment: Perfect Marcel...this does exactly what I want it to do. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many of these URLs do you have or have to redirect but here would be a quick and dirty approach which is only one of the ways you could do it. I would store the old urls in a simple "route table" with the number from the old url and new complete url from new app..

Create a route in routes.rb

`get 'rbt/:old_url', to: 'routes_controller#routing'`

Then in the RoutesController in your routing methods you do something like this:

```
def routing
  myid = params[:old_url].split('-').first
  redirect_to UrlTable.find(myid.to_i).url, :status => moved_permanently
end
```

I would also add a counter to see how many people still use the old url. I know it's not pretty but sure works.

Comment: Interesting approach. I was hoping I could do it from all within my `routes.rb` without having to go to the controller. What I really don't like about this, though, is having to hit the DB for any of the old URLs. Feels like a potential easy security vulnerability....i.e. if someone just hits bad, old URLs the app would be doing lots of DB checks and could be crippled easily. So I would much prefer an approach that just uses the `routes.rb` to examine the incoming URL request and does something without hitting the DB.

Comment: Hi, if they are all the same (as in stripped out html at the end, encoding and no "rbt") you could just do it with regex at route or web server level. If they all map to something different named you can do web server level as well. Depends on the amount. Thought it looked like some big database of news of blog articles, then my approach would at least work. Sure not the best approach in the world but working...should add a default though if not found.